# Python TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I write a simple for loop to extract out all the mps files in a directory.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir, topdown='true'):
    # filter the file names
    for filename in files:
        print(filename);  # this prints out filenames as expected
    print([file for filename in files if file[-4:] == '.mp3'])
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please post the full error backtrace.

Comment: Aside: `filename.endswith(".mp3")` works too.

Comment: @dublintech Sorry.  I have it.  My bad. I have asked for this to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
print([filename for filename in files if filename[-4:] == '.mp3'])
```